# Facing issue while trying to run Robot framework script in google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, robotframework

I am facing a Chrome popup while trying to run Robot Frame work script:

> Microsoft Security Essentials wants to restore your Chrome settings to their
>   original defaults.
>
> This will reset your homepage, new tab page and
>   search engine, disable your extensions, and unpin all tabs. It will
>   also clear other temporary and cached data, such as cookies, content
>   and site data.

In chrome extension, my developer mode is unchecked, whereas it should be checked.

The Robot Framework automation script is just to open the google Chrome browser and load google search page.

1. I am using Win 7 Home Basic OS.
2. I have attached screenshots.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Google chrome ext pic]

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with Robot Framework. Instead this issue is caused by Microsoft Security Essentials affecting Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that most [Chrome support specialists](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qO62rMPO05Q) will ask you to run an anti-malware tool to verify that your system is running normally. These can be found by searching on the popup message.

One [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/43j5a9/microsoft_essentials_wants_to_restore_my_chrome/) user commented that in his case the problem was resolved by altering the Windows registry:

> I finally found a fix for this. There is a setting in the registry
>   that's causing it.
>
> In the registry it's under
>   HKEY_CKU\CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\TriggeredReset
>
> Delete the TriggeredReset key and then close regedit. Fixed.
>
> This is an API for 3rd party programmers who want to create cleaning
>   tools. But if the tool isn't written properly, the triggered reset
>   never gets deleted and we have it always asking.